# Why does spark repartition take so much time on skewed data?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
Below is an analogic schema

Table 1 - Players (Upto 10M players per team, HUGE)
player_number - INT
team_id - bigint (indexed)

Table 2 - Team (Relatively small table which I want to broadcast)
team_id - bigInt (indexed)
team_size - INT
```

Use case - I want to create a join of team1 and team2 on team_id. Players' table can have a large skew on team_id. For team_id number of players can range between 10-10M.

- Approach 1 - I repartition players and team on team_id and do a sort-merge join. Repartitioning players takes close to 2.5mins due to large skew, and joining takes close to 3 seconds. **Hence overall time is close to 2.6mins**
- Approach 2 - Teams and players' tables are uniformly distributed, and I do a join without repartitioning on the same key. This takes around 20secs and **hence overall time is 20secs**

**Question** - Why does non-repartitioned join take less time than repartitioning. In sort-merge join, won't spark do an internal repartitioning on team_id; how is that different from approach 1. The skew is same for both the cases

Comment: As per Approach 2 " Teams and player' tables are uniformly distributed" how you have achieved/confirmed  this explicitly ...answers lies how DAGs created both approaches?

Comment: what version of spark are you on?

Comment: Have you enabled adaptive query? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html

Answer (score 3):

So we would need to look at the physical plan by using `.explain()` on the joined `DataFrame` to be completely sure but here is my assumption:

Spark detects that Table 2 is small enough to be **broadcasted** to each executor. Then each worker can join the tables on its own, avoiding shuffling and reducing the overall execution time.

In Approach 1 you are forcing Spark to do a repartition, which is not necessary.